# WinRM throws Error Code 2, "Unable to check the status of the Firewall" despite EVERYTHING

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, windows-firewall, winrm, subscription

I am trying to set up a source initiated event Subscription from a Windows 2019 server to a Windows 10 Client. I know that might sound backwards but I don't really have a choice for a variety of reasons. Both of these devices are domain joined, the server being the DC.

Anyways, I am getting an Error Code 2 "Unable to check the status of the Firewall" when I try to activate the subscription. It also says "The system cannot find the file specified". WinRM throws this error when I do "winrm qc" or "Set-WSManQuickConfig -force". To me this says that WinRM cannot see the firewall.

I have opened port 5895 and this didn't work. I made sure that the Firewall was active on Domain. I made sure the WinRM listeners have IP addresses. Eventually I just added an allow all rule only for it to not work (This is an internet isolated lab environment).

What the hell is going on? I'm ripping my hair out. If anyone could at least point me to some better logs that would be helpful. I already know about

Comment: Check if Windows Firewall is enabled, and do not use a "Client" operating system as a server, weird things will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Subscription looks for a specific Firewall rule for Winrm.
The rule name should be "Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)".
You can create an inbound firewall rule as follows:
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" dir=in action=allow service=any enable=yes profile=any localport=5985 protocol=tcp

Try after creating the above rule. The subscription should work.